# oVirt v4 network connectivity within VM's

Tags: virtualization, redhat, libvirt, ovirt, rhev

I'm running 2 instances of oVirt. the first is oVirt 3.5 and everything is great.

I recently set up `Version 4.0.1.1-1.el7.centos` and I'm having issues within VM's.

I spun up a VM from the Glance template for Centos 65 (`CentOS 6.5 64-Bit (7df3c30)`) (Side note this is the same for other centos VM's i've imported).

Once the VM is up it does not work with almost no yum mirror servers.

It all started with a yum update:

```
[root@test ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * updates: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
http://mirror.nexcess.net/CentOS/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.nexcess.net/CentOS/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
```

Upon investigation this times out:

```
[root@test ~]# curl http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
```

From the VM I have what appears to be find network connectivity, the host has no issues curling google, msn, etc. It seems to not be able to connect to any Yum mirror `repomd.xml` files however.

However that is 100% accessible from the VM master (the host that this VM is running on). I can curl, etc from the host. I cannot do this from the VM.

Any thoughts on how to resolve it? I can provide more information if needed.

**Edit**

This is where it gets weird. I can curl part of the mirror but not the repodata.

```
[root@test ~]# curl -vv http://linux.mirrors.es.net/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/
* About to connect() to linux.mirrors.es.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 198.129.224.35... connected
* Connected to linux.mirrors.es.net (198.129.224.35) port 80 (#0)
> GET /centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: linux.mirrors.es.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 16:47:06 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 1284
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
...snip....
* Closing connection #0


[root@test ~]# curl -vv http://linux.mirrors.es.net/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/
* About to connect() to linux.mirrors.es.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 198.129.224.35... connected
* Connected to linux.mirrors.es.net (198.129.224.35) port 80 (#0)
> GET /centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: linux.mirrors.es.net
> Accept: */*
>
...this times out...
```

as you can see i can curl the first fine from the vm, but if i add `/repodata` it times out

Comment: Does the VM ping the host? do you have network policies enabled? mac spoofing protection maybe? Do you use RHEV networking, OVS or Neutron provider? Have you tried asking at users@ovirt.org?

Comment: VM can ping the host, can get to google, can access local network. For the vNic Profile i set none, so there are no policies there. I use whatever the bridged networking is, it's a home computer running it, so ovirtmgmt network is a bridge to the wired connection. I haven't yet, but I'm headed to that point soon.

Comment: did you try the usual, like `yum clean all` etc? Also, does the host reach the same repos, e.g. `wget http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml` from the hypervisor, not the VM?

Comment: works from all other machines including the hypervisor, times out from within VM. I think I'm getting somewhere though, nsswitch.conf only had 'files' for all of its network lines, changed them to db files nis and i kept running yum clean all and yum update, it eventually found a working mirror (after trying about 20 mirrors that all were unconnectable). I have a working yum update running slowly now, going to see if the package updates help

Comment: I'd also make sure the VM's DNS is properly set.